# MYSQL Statement Issues - INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN WITH GROUP BY and MAX

Tags: mysql

I can't for the life of me get this statement to work.

```
SELECT max(pm.timestamp), pm.id, pm.p_media_user_id, pm.p_media_type, 
pm.p_media_file, pm.wall_post, pm.p_media_location,pm.p_media_location_name, 
pm.p_media_category, pa.p_source_alert_id, pa.post_id, pa.p_target_alert_id, 
pu.fb_id, pu.username, pu.city, pu.sex, pu.main_image 

FROM p_media as pm 

INNER JOIN p_users as pu ON pm.p_media_user_id = pu.fb_id 

LEFT JOIN p_alerts as pa ON pm.id = pa.post_id AND pa.p_source_alert_id ='3849084' 

group by pm.p_media_user_id;
```

The only thing that I am having issues with is the max(pm.timestamp), after the grouping I would expect it to show the NEWEST rows in the p_media table, but to the contrary it's doing the exact opposite and showing the oldest rows. So, I need the newest rows from the p_media table grouped by the user id which Join the p_users table.

Thanks in advance, if anyone helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you are aggregating by the `p_media_user_id` column but then selecting other non aggregate columns.  This either won't run at all, or it will run but give non determistic results.  However, it looks like you just want the most recent record from the `p_media` table, for each `p_media_user_id`. 
If so, then this would seem to be the query you intended to run:

```
SELECT
    pm1.timestamp, pm1.id, pm1.p_media_user_id, pm1.p_media_type, pm1.p_media_file,
    pm1.wall_post, pm1.p_media_location, pm1.p_media_location_name, 
    pm1.p_media_category, pa.p_source_alert_id, pa.post_id, pa.p_target_alert_id,
    pu.fb_id, pu.username, pu.city, pu.sex, pu.main_image 
FROM p_media as pm1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT p_media_user_id, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
    FROM p_media
    GROUP BY p_media_user_id
) pm2
    ON pm1.p_media_user_id = pm2.p_media_user_id AND
       pm1.timestamp = pm2.max_timestamp
INNER JOIN p_users AS pu
    ON pm1.p_media_user_id = pu.fb_id 
LEFT JOIN p_alerts AS pa
    ON pm1.id = pa.post_id AND
       pa.p_source_alert_id = '3849084';
```

Comment: *This either won't run at all*, it will sadly run in MySQL, but will give an error in almost all other databases. I say "sadly", because that hides the error and makes it harder to find. MySQL calls it in their docs *an extension to the standard*.

Comment: @RacilHilan It _won't_ run on MySQL if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode be enabled (or if `ANSI` mode be enabled, which includes the former).

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant by that sentence. You should add the explanation to your answer. Most MySQL installations don't change the defaults.

Comment: Good news! MySQL has finally addressed the problem and [starting with MySQL 5.7.5, the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes). The reason they gave is rather silly *because GROUP BY processing has become more sophisticated to include detection of functional dependencies.*, but at least they've changed the default and starting with MySQL 5.7.5, it will behave like most other databases.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not doing what you think it is doing. When you use `GROUP BY`, only the columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause can be used in the `SELECT` without an aggregate function. All columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause **MUST** be using in an aggregate function when adding them to the `SELECT`.

This is the standard, and for all databases that follow the standards, you will get an error from your query. For some reason, MySQL decided not to follow the standards on this and no error is returned. This is really bad, because your query will run, but the results cannot be predicted. So you will think that the query is fine and will wonder why you get the wrong results, while in fact your query is invalid.

MySQL has finally addressed the problem and [starting with MySQL 5.7.5, the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes). The reason they gave is rather silly: *because GROUP BY processing has become more sophisticated to include detection of functional dependencies.*, but at least they've changed the default and starting with MySQL 5.7.5, it will behave like most other databases. For earlier versions, if you have access to change the settings, I recommend enabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` so you get a clear error for such invalid queries.

In some cases, you really don't care about the value returned for the non-aggregate columns, if all the values are exactly the same. To let the query pass while `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled, use the `ANY_VALUE()` function on those columns. The is a better approach as it clearly indicate your intention.

To learn how you can fix your query, you can read [How do we select non-aggregate columns in a query with a `GROUP BY` clause](http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/04/group-by-non-aggregate-columns/). You need to self-join the `p_media` table with only the `p_media_user_id` and `MAX(timestamp)` selected on the grouping:

```
SELECT pm.timestamp, pm.id, pm.p_media_user_id, pm.p_media_type, pm.p_media_file,
       pm.wall_post, pm.p_media_location, pm.p_media_location_name, pm.p_media_category,
       pa.p_source_alert_id, pa.post_id, pa.p_target_alert_id,
       pu.fb_id, pu.username, pu.city, pu.sex, pu.main_image 
FROM p_media as pm
INNER JOIN (SELECT p_media_user_id, MAX(timestamp) AS max_time
            FROM p_media
            GROUP BY p_media_user_id
           ) pmm ON pm.p_media_user_id = pmm.p_media_user_id
                AND pm.timestamp = pmm.max_time
INNER JOIN p_users AS pu ON pm.p_media_user_id = pu.fb_id 
LEFT JOIN p_alerts AS pa ON pm.id = pa.post_id
                        AND pa.p_source_alert_id = '3849084';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an ORDER BY after the grouping and tell SQL what column you want to sort by [ASC or DESC].

```
SELECT max(pm.timestamp), pm.id, pm.p_media_user_id, pm.p_media_type, 
pm.p_media_file, pm.wall_post, pm.p_media_location,pm.p_media_location_name, 
pm.p_media_category, pa.p_source_alert_id, pa.post_id, pa.p_target_alert_id, 
pu.fb_id, pu.username, pu.city, pu.sex, pu.main_image 

FROM p_media as pm 

INNER JOIN p_users as pu ON pm.p_media_user_id = pu.fb_id 

LEFT JOIN p_alerts as pa ON pm.id = pa.post_id AND pa.p_source_alert_id ='3849084' 

group by pm.p_media_user_id
ORDER BY pm.p_media_user_id DESC;
```

Comment: That wont work, because that's only going to order the current results which are the wrong results all together. For instance, I'm getting back ID 54, 55, 58 and I need to be getting back the newest ID's for each user_id group which is 100, 104, 103, so order by will just change the 54,55,58 results ascending of descending. Thanks though